# Setting state by assignment

Tags: reactjs

In react, is there a reason why someone would want to set the state of a variable by assignment instead of calling setState(...)

Example:

```
// accessing state var directly
this.state.myVar = 'changed state'
// instead of calling setState
this.setState({myVar: 'changed state'})
```

To me this seems like an anti-pattern. But maybe there's a good explanation why sometimes it's necessary?

Answer (score 3):

It's necessary, because React has to know wether `this.state` is considered mutated. There is no dirty-checking in React. The state object is considered dirty when `this.setState` is called, and no further comparisons are made to its previous state. This answer might help explain this in more detail: [Why is React's concept of Virtual DOM said to be more performant than dirty model checking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109361/why-is-reacts-concept-of-virtual-dom-said-to-be-more-performant-than-dirty-mode)

Comment: So if I update a state var by doing: this.state.myVar ='changed var', the state object won't be considered dirty I assume? That would be a reason why someone would want to do this?

Comment: I think you should avoid mutating the state directly, it avoids confusing code and "why won't this update!?!" :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I think to. I was just curious to know if there are good reasons to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Setting (mutating) the state directly will work in this case:
`this.state.myVar = 'changed state'`
However, it should be avoided according to the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate):

> NEVER mutate `this.state` directly, as calling `setState()` afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat `this.state` as if it were immutable.

The main problem with mutating the state is that it prevents some of the React lifecycle methods from working. For example, React's `shouldComponentUpdate()` method is often used to speed up the app when dealing with a large number of components. The method allows you to skip re-rendering a component if the state has been updated:

```
// Return false if you want to skip the `render()` method
shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps, nextState) {
  return this.state.myVar === nextState.myVar;
}
```

The above will not work if you are mutating the state. `this.state.myVar` and `nextState.myVar` references are the same and therefore the above will always return `true`.