# React state assignment before setting state

Tags: javascript, object, reactjs, variable-assignment, state

I'm new to React and I'm following an online tutorial. The instructor presented the code below as part of a Todo App. It is the logic for adding a new `todo` item (object) to the `state`.

```
var TodoApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      todos: {}
    };
  },
  addTodo: function(todo) { 
    var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
    this.state.todos[`todo-${timestamp}`] = todo;
    this.setState({
      todos: this.state.todos
    });
  }
});
```

**1.** In this case, is it a good practice to assign the `todo` object to the state before calling `this.setState()`?  (This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32340812/setting-state-by-assignment) gives some related information.)
**2.** Wouldn't it be better to spread the `todos` as below?
**3.** Alternatively, is there a better way to update `state` in this setup?

```
var TodoApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      todos: {}
    };
  },
  addTodo: function(todo) { 
    var timestamp = (new Date()).getTime();
    this.setState({
      todos: {...this.state.todos, [`todo-${timestamp}`]: todo}
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: in first example you have mutated the state. You should not mutate the state, because of bugs and unpredictable beheviour. Second example looks good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, see example below & documentation.

   ```
   this.state.todos = ...
    // Someone modifies todo's state at this point
    this.setState({
      todos: this.state.todos // this would not do what you expected anymore
    });
   ```

> NEVER mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made

[React's documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate)

2. Absolutely, that's the React way. This is a perfect solution.
3. Spreading is good enough.