# React native: How to implement script tags

Tags: react-native

I am trying to implement an email api, and I've been given some code. Although I have no idea where to place it. At the moment im just getting errors with it.

```
export default class Contact extends Component {
  render() {
  return(
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v2/smtp.js">
Email.send("from@you.com",
"to@them.com",
"This is a subject",
"this is the body",
"smtp.yourisp.com",
"username",
"password");
</script>
```

Comment: Are you looking for answers for react or react-native? Those two are different things from each other. For more info check [React vs React-Native](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34641582/2315280)

Answer (score 0):

You ***can NOT*** have a script tag in react-native.
The script tag is not intended for react nor react native projects. The  tag is used to define a client-side script (JavaScript) in **HTML**
What you can do is use an already made library for react-native to send emails (like [react-native-mail](https://github.com/chirag04/react-native-mail))

Answer (score -1):

Put this in your `index.html` file:

```
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v2/smtp.js"></script>
```

and then use the code in your component:

```
export default class Contact extends Component {
  render() {

    window.Email.send("from@you.com", "to@them.com", "This is a subject", "this is the body", "smtp.yourisp.com", "username", "password");

    return (<div>Done</div>);
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: There is no 'index.html' file in react-native.