# react-native: Memory when using conditional render

Tags: react-native

For example I have View and in this View we have another View2 which is rendered conditionally. So if I will show and hide this View2 1000 times will it affect memory?

```
<View>
{condtion && <View><Text>2<Text><View>
<View>
```

Comment: Will something change each time? what's a condition to depend?

Comment: @errorau the content will change. Dynamically. For example different text .

Answer (score 0):

First `react` and `react-native` has a different concept of how classes react to each other.  [here is more details about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34641582/what-is-the-difference-between-react-native-and-react)

Also, you can use `redux` or other statement manager library like `mobix` `flux` and another alternative solution you can use `props` you code in main render function you can create/write a component like this

```
<ChangeTextComponent condition={you_condition}/>
```

When change you condition only render `ChangeTextComponent` component render.

```
class AnotherPage_Test extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <View>
          <ChangeTextComponent condition={you_condition}/> 
        </View>
    )
  }
```

}