# Is Redux the same for React and React native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am currently studying RN by myself, without prior knowledge in React. A lot of things seem to exist in both such as Redux and hooks. Many of the resources I find refer to React in the title (e.g "Redux Crash Course With React").

My question is: where does the line cross between React and React Native? Would I be fine studyig form these resources that refer to React, or would that just confuse me?

I'm trying to understand a go to approach to understand which resource I'd be fine with and which would be irrelevant.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34641582/what-is-the-difference-between-react-native-and-react?r=SearchResults)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React Native contains React library to use it as front-end library.

Most of usages of React are the same for React-Native. And it is same for Redux too.

React-Native must have other libraries to build applications that can run on both of Android and iOS.

Also it has middleware libraries that allow us to use most of native libraries' functionalities. As an example you can check [Alert directory](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Libraries/Alert) out. It is used for to show native Android alert dialogs.

Good luck..

Answer (score 3):

Both react and react native use javascript to create the user interface we need but the difference is in the rendering, style and bundling and you should know that react native is a framework itself but react.js is a library. the main difference:

---React-Native doesn’t use HTML to render the app, but provides alternative components that work in a similar way. Those React-Native components map the actual real native iOS or Android UI components that get rendered on the app.

---With React-Native, you’ll have to learn a completely new way to animate the different components of your app with Javascript.

--- navigating between pages are totally different!!!

so we conclude that it's better to study references based on RN not react.js . but some functionalities such as redux or hooks or a lot of it's components are exactly the same and you can study react.js references for them. only the 3 differents that i said above are important.

Comment: also check this 

https://medium.com/@alexmngn/from-reactjs-to-react-native-what-are-the-main-differences-between-both-d6e8e88ebf24