# Transpile React to React Native on a regular basis?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, transpiler

It might be a stupid question to ask, but searching on the web did not give me any conclusive result: **If you want to maintain only a single code base, does it make sense to write your code in React and transpile to React Native?** A client has the idea to have both an App (ideally for iOS and Android at the end) and a website all deduced from a single source.

I have some experience with webpack and I know it can be painful to configure, but is there some definite guide by Facebook on that issue which I missed?

**References**

- [Medium article by Sahil Sharma from 2016](https://medium.com/@sahilaug/react-native-transpiled-pure-native-or-hybrid-b4ccc6db6c63)
- [Medium article by Gwendolyn Faraday from 2017](https://medium.com/@gwen_faraday/converting-a-react-app-to-react-native-d7df17968fc6)
- [What is the difference between React Native and React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34641582/what-is-the-difference-between-react-native-and-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is to run your react-native application on the web. 
The go to library for that is [react-native-web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web).

Comment: I was indeed blinded by the fact that React code is already existing, but I feel starting from React-native might indeed be a cleaner approach.