# What are React App , are they mobile applications or website?

Tags: reactjs, web

I am learning React JS from YouTube , and the instructor some time uses a word "React App" ,
I am confused that why he uses this word in the tutorial of website .

Please clarify it .
Thank you

Comment: A “React app” is an application built using React. React is used to build web apps and React Native is used for mobile apps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between React Native and React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34641582/what-is-the-difference-between-react-native-and-react)

Comment: To add, the term application (app) does not necessarily mean "**mobile** application".
Application can be either a "web application" (which can be built with "React" framework and accessed using the browser) or a "mobile application" (which can be built with "React-Native" framework as a native mobile application installed on the mobile device and accessed through its icon).
"React **JS**" usually means "web application".

Comment: App doesn't indicate only Mobile application, An application, or application program, is a software program that runs on your computer. Web browsers, e-mail programs, word processors, games, and utilities are all applications. The word "application" is used because each program has a specific application for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a React and there is a React Native. They are two different things. React is an open-source, **front end**, JavaScript library for building user interfaces or UI(User Interface) components. That simply means React is for building front-end of websites/web apps. React Native is a JavaScript framework for writing real, natively rendering mobile applications for iOS and Android. That means React Native is for building mobile apps. React Native is based on React