# What is the difference between React, ReactJS, and React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to study a course about **React**, but I don't know couple of things, like:

What is the difference between **React**, **ReactJS**, and **React Native** ?

Well, if there is a big difference, What is the best one  of them to study ?


I am really looking forward to study it, so if you got any information on the best way to start learning this course, I would appreciate it.


Thank you so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between React Native and React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34641582/what-is-the-difference-between-react-native-and-react)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

React and React.Js are one and the same.

#### React / ReactJs

ReactJS is an open-source JavaScript library used to build the user interface for Web Applications. It is responsible only for the view layer of the application. It lets developers compose complex UIs from small and isolated pieces of code called "components". ReactJS is made up of two parts, first is components, which are the pieces that contain HTML code and what you want to see in the user interface, and the second is HTML document where all your components will be rendered.

#### React Native

React Native is an open-source JavaScript framework used for developing a mobile application for iOS, Android, and Windows. It uses only JavaScript to build a cross-platform mobile app. React Native is same as React, but it uses native components instead of using web components as building blocks. It targets mobile platforms rather than the browser.

[Link for Further information](https://www.javatpoint.com/reactjs-vs-reactnative)

#### What is the best one of them to study ?

React and React native both solve different kinds of problems. React is common library between react and react-native which provides supports for hooks and generates virtual dom.

`react-dom` will render content on web using virtual dom created by `react`.

However on other side `react-native` will create bundle for android and iOS.

Answer (score 1):

**Main differences between Reactjs and React Native**

1. When it comes to a web platform, Reactjs can be defined as a base
   derivative of React DOM, while React Native acts as a base
   derivative by keeping workflow and syntax the same alongside
   altering components.
2. React is a JavaScript library that can help your developers in
   building a highly responsive UI Layer and React Native on the other
   hand is a complete framework to develop cross-platform applications.
3. Virtual DOM is used to extract browser code in React; native APIs
   help in rendering components in mobile in React Native.
4. In React Native, UI is rendered with the help of JSX but the
   applications curated with Reactjs extract HTML in UI.
5. For styling in Reactjs, CSS is used, and React Native platform
   requires a stylesheet for styling.
6. Using CSS, you can carry out animation in Reactjs; for animation in
   React Native, you need to use an animated API.