# What is "Dirty" in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to understand React.js and often come across a term "Dirty" like 
dirty checker/checking, dirty data ,dirty model

I followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109361/why-is-reacts-concept-of-virtual-dom-said-to-be-more-performant-than-dirty-mode) but could not make out what actually the term **Dirty** convey & why we call it dirty.

Comment: For people who don't like React, the whole thing is dirty... ;)

Answer (score 12):

Dirty data - the data, that have been changed recently and DOM haven't been re-rendered according to this changes yet. So dirty checking is diff between next state and current state.

Comment: To be clear, "dirty-checking" isn't specific to React. It's just a term for one way of synchronizing application state to the DOM/UI. React uses something different: [reconciliation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html).

Answer (score 6):

Dirty is just the state of the form which tells that this form has been touched by user.
This does not means that form is invalid.