# How to cleanup dirty state in React and Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am facing this issue for weeks.
I asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344518/something-wrong-with-my-way-to-fetch-data) before, and I found out that this problem has to do with dirty state.

Basically, I created a page with a list of articles, and when you click one of them, it will take you to see an article. I am making AJAX GET request with componentDidMount for both articles and an article(you can see this code in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344518/something-wrong-with-my-way-to-fetch-data)).

I tried to find out a solution without asking here, but I couldn't. I am guessing that I have to add componentWillUnmount method in ArticlePage to cleanup my dirty state from previous page.
This is my action fetching articles for a list and each article.

```
export function fetchArticles(){
   return (dispatch) => {
      axios.get('/api/articles').then(({data}) => {
         dispatch({
            type: FETCH_ARTICLES,
            payload: data
         })
      })
    }
}
export function fetchArticle(id){
    return (dispatch) => {
       axios.get(`/api/articles/${id}`).then(({data}) => {
          dispatch({
             type: FETCH_ARTICLE,
             payload: data
          })
       })
    } 
 }
```

this is my reducer:

```
export default function(state=[], action){
   switch (action.type) {
      case FETCH_ARTICLES:
         return action.payload;
      case FETCH_ARTICLE:
         return action.payload;
    default:
         return state;
   }
 }
```

How can I cleanup dirty state?

Comment: So add a `RESET_ARTICLE` action? What's stopping you?

Comment: @azium It did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reducer should look like this:

```
export default function(state=[], action){
   switch (action.type) {
      case FETCH_ARTICLES:
         return action.payload;
      case FETCH_ARTICLE:
         return action.payload;
      case RESET_ARTICLE:
         return []; // return an empty state here.
    default:
         return state;
   }
 }
```

and in your component in `componentWillUnmount` trigger `RESET_ARTICLE` action.

Comment: @Dan So have you dispatched the action on the ```componentWillUnmount?``` Is that action dispatched? If not then you are not properly unmounting the component.

Comment: @skay- Yeah I did, and if I looked at Diff in my Redux DevTools, a state actually changes to [ ]. However, I still cannot go back to the previous page.

Comment: @Dan what do you mean you cannot go back to the previous state? Changing routes is another story. The impression i get from your question is that you simply want to reset the state not change page.

Comment: @skay- oh, I am sorry. you are right. I only asked how I reset my state here. I was including the another question I asked. I am just gonna accept this as the answer. sorry about that.