# How React Virtual DOM works when I set both the changed states and the unchanged states?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, virtual-dom

How React Virtual DOM diff between the old in-memory DOMs and the new in-memory DOMs? Specifically, is there any difference between that I just set the changed states and that I set both the changed states and the unchanged states? Is there any difference between set Object and Number?

For example:
The current state is `{name: 'Eric', id: '1234567890', others: {other1: 1, other2: 2}}`. Is the diff result `this.setState({name: 'Tiger'})` the same with the diff result `this.setState({name: 'Tiger', id: '1234567890', others: {other1: 1, other2: 2}})`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is React's concept of Virtual DOM said to be more performant than dirty model checking?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109361/why-is-reacts-concept-of-virtual-dom-said-to-be-more-performant-than-dirty-mode)

Comment: I don't think it is duplicate of that question. My core question is whether there is any difference between that I just set the changed states and that I set both the changed states and the unchanged states?

Comment: There is no - react merges the passed state object into the existing state object. And it does not diff the state, it diffs the virtual dom generated from the state.

Answer (score 0):

By default React triggers a re-render on all calls to `setState` whether the data has changed or not (see `setState` [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate)), so I would expect it to be identical in the cases you've described.

You can override how it behaves using [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate) if you need specific behaviour.

What this means for the actual content of the internal diff it uses is another story - I would expect them to be identical but it feels like a bad idea to rely on specifics of any of this behaviour.

Comment: "What this means for the actual content of the internal diff it uses is another story" --- "internal diff" works with the virtual DOM, not the state object.

Comment: @zerkms Aware of that, I suspect it would be a dangerous game to assume any specific implementation detail of how the vDOM is generated beyond the setState API though.

Comment: No need to assume: virtual dom is generated from components that you return from `render()`.

Comment: Is it a stable, documented API though? I'd love to read more if it is! For curiosity's sake though, I still don't think I'd rely on it for anything important.

Comment: Are you asking whether react's `render()` aka the main method is stable and documented? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html "setState() will always trigger a re-render unless conditional rendering logic is implemented in shouldComponentUpdate()". "I still don't think I'd rely on it for anything important" --- it is the foundation of React, you cannot "not rely" on it.

Comment: Not that, no, I mean the _internal_ specifics of how it _does_ that.