# using React inside Angular 2, ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined

Tags: angular, reactjs, react-dom

I'm trying to include a library written for react into my Angular 2 application, but ReactDOM seems to stay undefined to typescript whatever I try, even though the variable has content in chrome's javascript inspector.
([image of chrome error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeBq9.jpg), and an 
[image of chrome breakpoint right before error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ernzV.png))

To isolate the problem I've looked at other attempts at combining the two, but found only solutions for Angular 2 Beta and React versions < 1.0.0  - so I took one of them (github.com/LookLikeAPro/Angular-2-React-Example), updated the packages and modified the code, and finally ran into the same error.

My fork can be found here: github.com/aJonathanSchneider/Angular-2-React-Example-fork, commands to start it are

```
npm install
npm start
```

Types for ReactDOM are exposed like this:

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/react-dom/index.d.ts" />
import ReactDOM = __React.__DOM;

export default ReactDOM;
```

The Angular component which should include a react component looks like this:

```
import React from "./react";
import ReactDOM from "./react-dom";
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'react-component',
    template:
        '<div [id]="id">wrapper</div>'
    ,
    inputs: ['component', 'props']
})
export class ReactComponent {
    component: any;
    props: Object;
    id: number;
    drawNode: any;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999999);
    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.drawNode = document.getElementById(this.id.toString());
        this.render();
    }
    ngOnChanges() {
        if (this.drawNode) {
            this.render();
        }
    }
    render() {
        ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(this.component, this.props), this.drawNode);
    }
}
```

And this is the order of scripts inside my index.html:

```
 <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
 <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>

 <script src="node_modules/react/dist/react.min.js"></script>
 <script src="node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
 <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
 <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
 <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
 <script>var __React = React;</script>
 <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script> 
 <script>
      System.import('app/main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
 </script>
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Combining react and angular is a *really* bad idea. By importing reactDOM, you're essentially loading competing virtual DOMs and event loops. Stop now and choose one or the other.

Comment: even if most of the time the gui would mostly either consist of one or the other? I'm trying to build a blender-like node editor, and [this](https://github.com/projectstorm/react-diagrams) was the only library under MIT license or similar that I could find. So it would be either the node editor or other content

Comment: That looks pretty cool. I'd suggest just using React for your webapp rather than angular. Maybe start with the Storm library and go from there.

Comment: I'm looking into using react now after reading more direct comparisons about the two. So to answer the question, could you point out where it'll ultimately fail? Because Angular 2 is often being described as an out-of-the-box framework where you replace modules later on if needed, whereas React is described as the V in MVC where you have to choose additional modules by yourself. That there's a functional core-overlap which makes the two completely incompatible isn't really clear (and even seems to have worked in beta versions)

Comment: Basically Angular is a super-set of React. So you get the modular component features already with Angular. To mimic app state you would normally add Redux to React, but Angular includes that natively. While you can combine the two, it's a poor technical approach and burdens your app with multiple, overlapping, and even competing frameworks.

Answer (score -1):

While it's possible to combine Angular 2 and React, it's considered a bad technical approach. Although Angular is a modular framework, trying to use React to replace the UI modules will lead to more errors. The reason is that React and Angular take sometimes very different approaches while creating a user interface,
 use different event loops to capture user interaction and can have competing access to the DOM. Angular [does change detection through zone.js](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html) and React [builds a virtual DOM to generate real DOM patches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109361/why-is-reacts-concept-of-virtual-dom-said-to-be-more-performant-than-dirty-mode). So basically there's no React-to-Angular interface.

Moreover, React is build around the unidirectional paradigm, whereas Angular has two-way data binding, which will make Components work very differently.

[This article](https://www.toptal.com/front-end/angular-vs-react-for-web-development) compares the two pretty well. The author creates the same application once in Angular and once in React with additional libraries.