# Append items ordering by placed amount

Tags: javascript, jquery, insert, append

I'm using this function to append new items in order by the amount. This function is being called every 30-50ms.

```
var insertBefore = false;
container.find('.roll-user-row[data-user-id="' + user_data.id + '"]').remove();

container.children().each(function () {
    var betContainer = $(this), itemAmount = $(this).attr('data-amount'), betId = $(this).attr('data-user-id');
    if (itemAmount < betData.totalAmount) {
        insertBefore = betContainer;
        return false;
    }
});

if (insertBefore) {
    $(template).insertBefore(container);
} else {
    container.prepend(template);
}
```

`itemAmount = $(this).attr('data-amount')` is integer, `betData.totalAmount` is interger too. And if appending goes slower than ±300ms - everything works well. In case of fast appending I get this result:

[image: random order]

and thats not even close what I want - thats random. How to solve this?

Comment: do you intend for every item in the list to be sorted at all times?

Comment: i.e is your aim a sorted list?

Answer (score 4):

**1. Refactoring**

First of all, `return` within `.each` callback doesn't work. It just breaks current iteration, not all the cycle. If you want to interrupt cylce, you should use simple for-loop and `break` statement. Then, I would recommend to call `$()` as rarely as possible, because this [is expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info). So I would suggest the following refactoring for your function:

```
function run() {
  container.find('.roll-user-row[data-user-id="' + user_data.id + '"]').remove();

  var children = container.children();
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    var betContainer = $(children[i]); // to cache children[i] wrapping
    var itemAmount = betContainer.attr('data-amount');
    var betId = betContainer.attr('data-user-id');

    if (itemAmount < betData.totalAmount) {
      $(template).insertBefore(container);
      return; // instead of "break", less code for same logic
    }
  }

  container.prepend(template); // would not be executed in case of insertBefore due to "return"
}
```

**2. Throttling**

To run a 50ms repeating process, you are using something like `setInterval(run, 50)`. If you need to be sure, that `run` is done and this is 300ms delay, then you may use just `setInterval(run, 300)`. But if the process initializes in a way that you can't change, and 50ms is fixed interval for that, then you may protect `run` calling by [lodash throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#throttle) or [jquery throttle plugin](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/debounce/):

```
var throttledRun = _.throttle(run, 300); // var throttledRun = $.throttle(300, run);
setInterval(throttledRun, 50);
```

`setInterval` is just for example, you need to replace your initial `run` with throttled version (`throttledRun`) in your repeater initialization logic. This means that `run` would not be executed until 300ms interval has passed since the previous `run` execution.

Comment: It looks like the right answer but I can't mark it correct as it creates queue of waiting appends with throttle. And what I need is real time update as there are 15 seconds to append all elements. After those 15 seconds I would just have to cancel throttle without appending new elements, right? Correct my if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Sandra Throttling just skips unwanted calls, it does not create a queue. So we have, say, throttled real time here. You may cancel trailing throttled invokation by `throttledRun.cancel()`. Just call it somewhere you need. Also you may override all the procedure to make it dummy: `run = function() { return null; }` or add a condition for preventive `return` or... There are a lot of ways for any use case, just need to clarify the use case.

Comment: so I tried this method and still faced the same issue.. the callbacks are in random time range, between 50 and ±300ms. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Sandra I believe, your issue could be easily fixed and the thing that could help to do it is reproducable demo. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net), [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/) or whatever would be a good option for repro. The problem is somewhere out of the code you provided in the question.

Answer (score 2):

I am only posting the approach here, if my understanding is right, then I'll post a code. First thing came to my mind reading this was the ['Virtual DOM' concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109361/why-is-reacts-concept-of-virtual-dom-said-to-be-more-performant-than-dirty-mode). Here is what you can do,

1. Use highly frequent random function calls only to maintain a data structure like an object. Don't rely on DOM updates.
2. Then use a much less frequent `setInterval` repetitive function call to redraw (or update) your DOM from that data structure.

I am not sure there are any reason you can't take this approach, but this will be the most efficient way to handle DOM in a time critical use-case.

Comment: The "30ms frequent function calls" is not the real thing, I just named it. This is actually socket emit's from backend depending of what happened on server side. And thats why it is 30-50-100ms - on the other hand random.

Comment: It doesn't matter, random or not, you can cleanly update a data structure. Then use that to generate the view.